# Fetch Post Request not returning payload but return status code (200)

Tags: reactjs, express, react-redux, fetch-api

So I am trying to create a user using redux-form. I have an express post route on the backend. NOTE: using redux-thunk for middleware, whatwg-fetch with webpack and babel-polyfill.

```
routes.post('/signup', async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const createdUser = await userController.createUser(req.body);
    const JSONCreatedUser = JSON.stringify(createdUser);
    res.json({
      confirmation: 'success',
      result: createdUser,
    });
    return JSONCreatedUser;
  } catch (error) {
    res.statusMessage = error.toString();
    res.status(409).json({
      confirmation: 'failure',
      error: error.toString(),
    });
  }
});
```

So the problem I am having is that when I use postman. I will get the entire user object back.

[image]
But when I submit it using form I only get

[image]

Apimanager.js

```
export const signUserUpApi = async (url, params) => {
  try {
    const response = await fetch(url, {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      },
      body: JSON.stringify(params),
    });

    const { status, statusText } = response;
    if (status === 409) {
      throw new Error(statusText);
    }
    return response;
  } catch (error) {
    throw new Error(error.toString());
  }
};
```

action.js

```
import constants from '../constants';
import { signUserUpApi } from '../utils/APIManager';

const signUserUpUrl = process.env.SIGN_USER_UP_URL || 'http://localhost:3000/user/signup';

export const signUserUp = (user) => {
  return async (dispatch) => {
    try {
      const createdUser = await signUserUpApi(signUserUpUrl, user);
      dispatch({
        type: constants.SIGN_USER_UP,
        user: createdUser,
      });
      return createdUser;
    } catch (error) {
      throw new Error(error);
    }
  };
};

export const signUserIn = (user) => {
  return {
    type: constants.SIGN_USER_UP,
    user,
  };
};
```

What I am trying to do is to get the User Object I created when I submit the form and redirect back to the page.

This is what I get back and it did create the user.
[image]

First thing, I need is why am I getting the https status code back and not the user object?

Second thing, what are the ways to redirect to the home page when a user successfully signed up logged in.

Comment: `POST` sends data to the server.  Why would you expect something to come back?

Comment: You are right. I think I am losing my mind!!!!!!!!

Comment: :) Well, you all set then?